python socket recv timeout while Wireshark shows received UDP packet (windows)
I have the following diagram:

Send:  client --(tx_socket)--> server
Reply:  server -- (rx_socket) --> client

def connect(self) -> None:
    self.tx_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.tx_socket.bind(("", self.tx_src_port))

    self.rx_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.rx_socket.settimeout(3.0)
    self.rx_socket.bind(("", self.rx_dst_port))

However, I always get timeout error when waiting for reply from server, even when Wireshark shows the reply packet:
self.tx_socket.sendto(command_str, (self.dst_addr, self.tx_dst_port))
self.rx_socket.recv(4096) # <--- TimeoutError

Somehow, this can be solved by sending a character from client to server using rx_socket in advance:
self.rx_socket.sendto("\n".encode('ascii'), (self.dst_addr, self.tx_dst_port))

But I do not understand why this happens. Also, the same issue does not exist in Linux.
Can you give me an explaination ? Any reply is greatly appreciated.

TL;DR: don't use different ports/sockets for sending and receiving.
Sending from one port but receiving on another will cause trouble with stateful firewalls, network address translation etc. The transmitted packet will create a state in the middlebox (firewall, router) and to match this  state any reply packet needs to be targeted at the original sender, i.e. same IP and port. Any other packets will not match any existing state and will thus be discarded by the middlebox, resulting in the packet loss and the timeout you experience.

Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately i am not responsible for the server side. It always listen on 192.168.1.100:53001 and send the reply to 192.168.1.200:53000 . You explain that the transmitted packet will create a state. What is this state and why does opening another socket has anything to do with it ?

@TranNguDang: A state is an association between sender and recipient, usually based on ip, port and protocol. It is usually used to enforce that incoming data are only allowed if they are a reply to outgoing data. Since the second socket with a different port is not part of the original association the incoming reply does not match a state and thus gets discarded. By sending from the receiver socket you created a new state which matches the reply.

Sockets are bi-directional. There is no good reason for the client to use 2 sockets when 1 socket will suffice for both sending and reading. Particularly with UDP. Using fewer ports also makes firewall/router administration easier
